# Drag the item of Reorder list not scroll till end of list item

Tags: flutter

My widget tree like,
Column -> Expanded -> Listview.builder -> List item -> Column[
TextView,
ReorderableListView.builder(),
]

I am trying to drag the item from reorder list to the end of list, But while drag the item to bottom of screen from reorder list, not able to scroll reorder list items while reach the bottom of the mobile screen, it is not scroll till last item of list. I am facing this issue when I have more items in the reorder list.

I require to scroll the reorder list till end when drag item from list.

Here is my code:

```
Column(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
  children: [
    Expanded(
      child: ListView.builder(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemCount: listOfString!.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Text(listOfString[index].name),
                ReorderableListView.builder(
                  physics: const ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                  itemCount: listOfString[index].department.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, departmentIndex) {
                    return Text(
                      listOfString[index].department[departmentIndex].name,
                      key: Key('$departmentIndex'),
                    );
                  },
                  onReorder: (int oldIndex, int newIndex) {},
                )
              ],
            );
          }),
    ),
  ],
)
```